# Will calling a nested Navigation Property retrieve all the parent navigation properties?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework inside an asp.net mvc web application. I have the following query:-

```
public AccountDefinition GetCustomer2(int id){

var c =   entities.AccountDefinitions.Where(s=>s.ORG_ID==id)
.Include(a=>a.SDOrganization)
.Include(a1=>a1.SiteDefinitions);
var c2 = c.Select(a=>a.SDOrganization);   //code goes here     }
```

Which is called from the following Action Method:-

```
public ActionResult Index(int searchTerm)
        {   var accountdefinition = repository.GetCustomer2(searchTerm).ToList();

            return View(accountdefinition);

 }
```

1. So when I am creating the c2 var will it query the database or the data will be inside the memory from the first call, when reaching the .Tolist()?.
2. Second question if I replace the .Include with .Select when creating the Var c,  will it have the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can see what query is executed in the SQL Server Profiler (if using SQL Server), or you can have a look at some Entity Framework Tracing Provider. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32

This will give you lots of information and understanding...